# Why TCPDF result doesn't show if I have lof of data?

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

I have developed a software with PHP and report with TCPDF. It runs well, but after importing lot of data in MySQL, the PHP can't produce the report before the browser times out. I've tried with the latest firefox and Chrome versions.

This my script:

```
     <?php

    require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

    // create new PDF documentation
     include "koneksi.php"; //file conection

     $bln=$_POST[BLN];  //for catch month
     $thn=$_POST[THN];  //for catch year
     $exp=$_POST[EXP];  //for catch expedition name


     if(empty($exp))
     {    
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_exp_local where  bulan = '$bln'  AND tahun = '$thn'";
     }
     elseif($exp != "")
     {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_exp_local where  bulan = '$bln'  AND tahun = '$thn' AND nama_exp = '$exp'";
     }  
       $hasil = mysql_query($sql);


       $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

       // set font
       $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 11);



    // landscape
       $pdf->addPage( 'L', 'LETTER' );

  //this for convert html to pdf with html function    

       $html = '
    <table border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="4">
        <tr><td colspan="9" align="center"><h2>Form Pantauan Expedisi Export</h2></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="center"><b>Tanggal</b></th>
            <th align="center"><b>Nama Expedisi</b></th>
            <th align="center"><b>Nama Distributor</b></th>
            <th align="center"><b>Kota Tujuan</b></th>
            <th align="center"><b>No Faktur</b></th>
            <th align="center"><b>Kondisi Armada Pengiriman</b></th>
            <th align="center"><b>Ketepatan Jumlah</b></th>
            <th align="center"><b>Ketepatan Waktu Kirim</b></th>
            <th align="center"><b>Keterangan</b></th>
        </tr></table>';

       while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
       {

         $html .= '<table border="1"><tr><td align="center">'.$data['tgl'].'</td>
                       <td align="center">'.$data['nama_exp'].'</td>
                       <td align="center">'.$data['nama_dist'].'</td>
                       <td align="center">'.$data['kota_tujuan'].'</td>
                       <td align="center">'.$data['faktur'].'</td>
                       <td align="center">'.$data['konarmada'].'</td>
                       <td align="center">'.$data['tepatjml'].'</td>
                       <td align="center">'.$data['tepatwaktu'].'</td> 
                       <td align="center">'.$data['ket'].'</td>  
                       </tr></table> ';

       }

       $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, ''); //for generate




       $pdf->Output('FormPantauExpLocalAll', 'I'); // for generate pdf file

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Server timeout does not depend on browser. Try using [set_time_limit(60)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) inside your loop:

```
   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
   {
       set_time_limit(60);
       $html .= '(...)';
   }
```

Also, try adding INDEX to your DB on (bulan, tahun, nama_exp) columns, it should speed up the retrieval process. Also, be aware that you may have run out of memory during the process (check your PHP logs on your server)

Comment: I have try all of your advice, but still not running. any solution for it?

Comment: not, the browser only blank, if i refresh the browser will do it again, until long time and blank again. If I choose the month with little data, the pdf generate normally.

Comment: do you have display_errors turned on? Looks like it uses too much memory for me. Try changing assigned memory in php.ini

Comment: Now i Try to optimize mysql table, and I still dont know what must I change in php.ini? because search "assigned memory" and notfound

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15046/discussion-between-septiyo-and-jderda)